# How to add gradle copy task

Tags: android, gradle

How can I add a `gradle` task to copy a file from a path to another path like:

`subModulName\build\generated\source\debug\com\name\pc`

create this directory in build time :

`mainModulesub\build\generated\source\debug\com\name\pc`

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow task to root gradle (top-level)

```
task copyApk(type: Copy) {
    from "app/build/outputs/apk/release/"
    into "app/build/"
    rename "app-release.apk", "yourAppName-release.apk"
}
```

run this task by using command line (in root project, or android studio terminal):

```
./gradlew copyApk
or
gradle copyApk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below script, It will also append date in apk name

```
task copyFile(type: Copy) {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd')
    from('PATH_WHERE_YOUR_APK_IS_PRESENT')
    include('PATH_WHERE_WHERE_TO_COPY_APK')
    rename ('app-release.apk', 'app-release'+formattedDate+'.APK')
    into('release/')
```